# laravel join 4 tables

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I started to learn the Laravel 5.8 framework and got a problem. The problem relates more to designing a database. But a solution is needed for Laravel (preferably Eloquent ORM).

The task is this: There is an online flower shop. The site has a category "Bouquets". Bouquets have a certain size (S, M, L ...). The size consists of the number of flowers in the bouquet, the height of the bouquet, diameter. Moreover, each size can have one name but a different number of flowers, height and diameter.

For example:

- size- "S": count 21, height 50cm, width 40cm.
- size- "S": count 15, height 50cm, width 30cm.

Each size can belong to different bouquets (relationship to many to many).

The administrator can choose an existing size for a new bouquet or create a new size. He sets the name, count, height and diameter. In this case, one bouquet can have several sizes ("S", "M" ...).

The bouquets also have photos that should change after choosing the size. There is also a price that also changes with size changing.

Now tables and links:

**bouquets_table**

```
id
name
```

**sizes_table**

```
id
name // "S", "M" ...
count
height
```

**prices**

```
id
price
```

**photos**

```
id
photo
```

I created a many-to-many relationship between these **bouquet_size** tables

```
bouquet_id
size_id
```

In models Bouquet and Size prescribed belongsToMany ().

And now, actually, the main questions are: Is it possible to add price_id and photo_id fields to the intermediate table bouquet_size and get it all through Pivot (I think this is wrong).

How to link all 4 tables so that when choosing the size of a bouquet, a photo and price for this bouquet would be selected. I consider it wrong to assign each bouquet my price and photo, as I want one bouquet to have different sizes and different photos and price depending on the size.

If it is possible in the answer, tell me how to implement all this in models (code).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have answered your question yourself already. :) "Is it possible to add `price_id` and `photo_id` fields to the intermediate table `bouquet_size` and get it all through Pivot?" Yes, it is and I think it would be the most appropriate solution here. Like you said, you "want one bouquet to have different sizes and different photos and price depending on the size," which means the the photo and price depends on the bouquet and size pair. Therefore your pivot table could contain the `bouquet_id`, `size_id`, `price_id` and `photo_id` values.

You could create a `BouquetSize` pivot model and define a `photo` and `price` relationship on it:

```
public function photo()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Photo');
}

public function price()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Price');
}
```

Then you could defined your `sizes` relationship on your `Bouquet` model as follows:

```
public function sizes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Size')
    ->using('App\BouquetSize')
    ->withPivot([
        'photo_id',
        'price_id',
    ]);
}
```

Then you would be able to access the price of a bouquet for a size like this, for example, `>>> $bouquet->sizes()->first()->pivot->price`.

See the "Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models" [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify the classes a little bit so that your app makes sense easier.
Leave *sizes_table*, *photos*, *prices* tables as is.
Replace *bouquets_table* with two others.

```
// the master/main bouquet table
main_bouquets table
id
name

// variations table for each main bouquet with the specified color, price etc
bouquet_variations table
id
main_bouquet_id
price_id
size_id
photo_id
```

So now you each variation of the bouquet is stored in bouquet_variations table that should be represented with a different model and inside that you can add any customisation for each side, color, price and any other attribute you might think.

It may be a bit more work for now but trust me it will help you very much as your application grows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I decided to do a little differently. Simply add the price field to the connected bouquet_size table, and remove the photo table. Instead of a photo table, do this: When creating a new bouquet and adding photos to it, save the photo on the server named bouquet_id + size_id + photo category (main photo, extra photo ...). Jpg. How do you like think?

Comment: The trick with the photos is clever. But I still think it might cause you troubles in the future. I usually develop my apps in a way that each part is decoupled from the others. These makes it easy to add new features in the future, meaning you have already set the basis for the updates/upgrades. If it is a small project (maybe for school) you can leave it as you said. If you are planning to make it a public project and continue developing it I suggest you follow my way or something else that will not cause you troubles in the future.